# Matlab Spell anaylsis - Independence criteria on Date

Tags: matlab, pivot-table, analysis

I am working with a quite a simple data set, essentially it consists of two columns, the first specifies a Date and the second a Wind speed as such:

```
05/12/1996 18:00    3.3169
13/12/1996 18:00    7.12648
13/12/1996 21:00    9.54931
14/12/1996 00:00    11.0114
26/12/1996 15:00    8.2517
12/01/1997 09:00    9.95154
12/01/1997 12:00    7.31349
12/01/1997 15:00    6.67902
...
```

I need to undertake a spell analysis on this data, that is to determine the number of events in which the wind blows between 2-4, 4-6, 6-8>ms^2, however these events need to be grouped into hour based groups.
Ideally I would like to end up with a table which looks something like this:

```
Spell analysis - Number of events at set duration and speed

Wind speed [m/s]    <=3hrs  6hrs    9hrs    12hrs   15hrs&>
 2-4                    1     -       -       -         -
 4-6                    -     -       -       -         -
 6-8>                   2     1       1       -         -
```

I can do this grouping manually using a pivottable in excel, however this is incredibly tedious as I would have to seperate each dataset into grouped velocities before using the pivottable to group into timed events. Furthermore I have to undertake this task for LOTS of datasets so a matlab routine is essential.

I have already created a matlab function to seperate a larger dataset into 12 smaller sets which contains wind directions from 0-30 deg, 30-60deg ....330-360deg, but this is a much more difficult step and I am struggling to think how to set an independence criteria on the dates and wind velocities. ANY help would be greatly appreciated as Im begining to pull out my hair on this one.

Sorry if I have confused anybody with this one,

Regards,
 Chris

Comment: Are you also asking how to parse the text file into usable numeric data or do you know how to do that?

Comment: Also, are these hour-based groups depending on the time difference between subsequent measurements or also spanning across multiple measurements?